# OmegaT used with latex files lose end of oline (EOL)

Tags: translate

I am trying to do a translation of a latex project using OmegaT CAT Tool (ver 4.1.1.) on Windows ([OmegaT project](http://www.omegat.org/)).

The problem is that the target (output) files lose proper line endings (EOL) characters.
I am working on Windows, so EOL = CRLF (\r\n)

First problem is that all CRLF are converted to LF
The second, which is more frustrating is that some of CRLF are deleted at all which makes the whole output (translated latex files) corrupted.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

If only all CRLF were converted to LF it could be simply replaced in the editor or I could set LF as the EOL in my TexStudio editor, but the removal of all the line endings is a real pain.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a tex question really. tex itself doesn't mind what line endings you use `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` are all treated equally in web2c based tex such as miktex or texlive.

Comment: yes, the real problem is that line endings are totally removed in some parts of documents. Maybe there are some tools that could fix such files e.g. make sure that the \item tag is always at the beginning of the new line when in enumerate environment etc. ("tidy" tools)

Comment: yes but that seems to be completely off topic here the fact you've used some tool that's dropped lines doesn't seem related to tex, can't you just edit the files to add say `[LINEEND]`  at the end of every line, then translate then remove the markers?

Comment: OK, If you believe it's not for this forum then I can delete it. There are lots of other questions on this forum that relate to external translators and OmegaT is simply one of them that also claims to support latex which is not so common in the CAT software world

Comment: If the dropping of the lines is somehow related to the tex syntax you could bring it back on topic perhaps but as far as I understand your question it's just treating the tex file as text and dropping eol for some reason so any fix is likely to be about that software rather than about tex. No need to delete the question, someone may answer.